# using indexes to replace NaN based on the whether or not an NaN is in a second vector

Tags: matlab, indexing, nan

I have two vector, "A" and "B". Both can contain NaN elements. I want to replace the "NaN" elements in B with "0" ONLY if the equivalent element in A is a non-NaN. I can do this easily with For- and If-loops, but because I want to understand better about using indexes, and my assumption that using indexes with large data sets would be faster(?), I tried the following:

```
    A = [1,2,3,NaN,5,6,NaN,8,9,10];
    B = [NaN,2,3,NaN,5,6,NaN,NaN,9,10];
    [Bindex] = isnan(B);
    B(~isnan(A(Bindex))) = 0;
```

This replaced only B(1), but not B(8). What am I missing about using indexes?

Answer (score 2):

If you printed the value of `B` after those statements you'd see that you're not only not replacing `B(8)` with zero, but you're also erroneously replacing `B(4)` with zero, even though `A(4)` is `NaN` and so `B(4)` does not match your zeroing out criterion.

Here's what's going on:

```
Bindex = isnan(B); # there's no need for brackets around Bindex
```

The above statement returns a logical array with ones wherever `B` contains a `NaN`.

```
Bindex =
   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
```

Now, when you index into `A` using `Bindex`, [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) takes place, and only those elements from `A` which have a corresponding `true` value in `Bindex` are extracted. This means the expression `A(Bindex)` yields

```
1   NaN   NaN     8    # A(1), A(4), A(7), A(8)
```

So then the expression `B(~isnan(A(Bindex))) = 0` is using a `1x4` vector instead of the original `1x10` vector, and ends up setting elements `B(1)` and `B(4)` to zero.

What you need is

```
B(isnan(B) & ~isnan(A)) = 0;
```

Now the value of `B` is

```
B =
     0     2     3   NaN     5     6   NaN     0     9    10
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work for you:

```
B(xor(isnan(A), isnan(B))) = 0
```

Comment: This yields the correct result for the given set of inputs, but fails for cases where `A` contains `NaN` at an index where `B` doesn't. XORing will set the corresponding element in `B` to zero.